# Rename a sequence of names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, variables, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe in pandas containing 11 columns. These columns are all named "subsidence".

I would like to rename the columns "subsidence 1", "subsidence 2", "subsidence 3" etc. Is there a quicker way to do this than using `df.rename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `df.columns` directly with a list comprehension:

```
df.columns = ['subsidence '+str(i) for i in range(1, 12)]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help again @jpp.

Comment: As an add on; say i wanted to rename in a range of floats instead of integers. Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes, very much like you suggest. Using my original example: "subsidence 1.1", "subsidence 1.2", "subsidence 1.3" etc.

Comment: Right. So I can't have `['subsidence '+str(i) for i in range[1.1, 1.3]]`

Comment: No, `range` only accepts integers, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Comment: use `numpy`, `np.arange(1.1,2,.2)`, `array([1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9]) `

Comment: You could get something close by iterating over a range of integers as before but doing str(i/10) instead of str(i).

Comment: Thanks everyone, combining all your suggestions I have `list =np.arange(1.1,1.21,.01)` and 
`df.columns = ['subsidence'+str(i) for i in list]` which gives me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of utitlizing the string operations provided by pandas if and only if `these columns are all named "subsidence"` i.e:

```
df.columns + ' ' + np.arange(1,len(df.columns)+1).astype(str)
```

Based on earlier comment simply :

```
df.columns + ' ' +  np.arange(1.1,1.21,.01)
```